# dig +trace does not map IP addresses to host names

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, reverse-dns

I manage four different public nameservers. I have noticed that two of them will map the IP addresses to host names in the Received lines when using the dig +trace command from the server command line and the other two do not. How can I ensure that reverse mapping always occurs?

What I don't want is this (using grep to show just the problem lines in the otherwise normal trace output):

```
    # dig +trace +add any google.com | grep Received
    ;; Received 508 bytes from 172.16.2.1#53(172.16.2.1) in 14 ms
    ;; Received 504 bytes from 199.7.83.42#53(199.7.83.42) in 378 ms
    ;; Received 164 bytes from 192.26.92.30#53(192.26.92.30) in 193 ms
    ;; Received 404 bytes from 216.239.36.10#53(216.239.36.10) in 286 ms
```

I get the above output using dig 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 on Debian Wheezy on two different nameservers. There is no problem doing reverse lookups on these or other IP addresses.

What I do want is this:

```
    # dig +trace +add any google.com | grep Received
    ;; Received 508 bytes from 196.29.32.61#53(196.29.32.61) in 0 ms
    ;; Received 488 bytes from 198.97.190.53#53(h.root-servers.net) in 284 ms
    ;; Received 164 bytes from 192.35.51.30#53(f.gtld-servers.net) in 212 ms
    ;; Received 404 bytes from 216.239.36.10#53(ns3.google.com) in 209 ms
```

I get the above using dig 9.7.3 and 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-38.el7_3.2

All nameservers have similar resolv.conf files, with just the line "nameserver ipaddress", where "ipaddress" is the IP address of the server itself.

In all other respects I have no problems with the way the nameservers are working. The +trace option is obviously very handy for diagnostics, and it would be much more convenient to have the intermediate nameserver hostnames displayed rather than IP addresses. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this on Debian squeeze / DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u10-Debian. If you are able to consistently perform reverse lookups (i.e. `dig -x 216.239.36.10`) as you have suggested, this sounds like it has something to do with the specific compilations of those dig binaries. Unless someone has better insights, this is unlikely to be solved without comparing the compile options and source code used for those builds.

Comment: Tracing is disabled by default. When tracing is enabled, dig
  makes iterative queries to resolve the name being looked up. It will follow
  referrals from the root servers, showing the answer from each server that was
  used to resolve the lookup.